# Builing a TCP Server from Scratch in VB.NET, but It only receives requests. It doesn't return responses to the client

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, visual-studio-2013

The code below is a class for a Windows TCP Server I need to have built from scratch which prints the output from a client that attempts to send a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

This server listens to localhost 127.0.0.1 on port 8080 and does that very well, however I am unable to make this server return a response to the Client.

So as it stands right now, the only thing that clients can do is send requests to this server but clients will never get a response back from this server.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class TCPControl
    Public Event MessageReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)

    Public ServerIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
    Public ServerPort As Integer = 8080

    Public Server As TcpListener

    Private CommThread As Thread
    Public IsListening As Boolean = True

    'CLIENTS
    Private Client As TcpClient
    Private ClientData As StreamReader

    Public Sub New()
        Server = New TcpListener(ServerIP, ServerPort)
        Server.Start()

        CommThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        CommThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Listening()
        ' CREATE LISTENING LOOP
        Do Until IsListening = False
            ' ACCEPT INCOMING CONNECTIONS
            If Server.Pending = True Then
                Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient
                ClientData = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)
            End If

            ' RAISE EVENT FOR INCOMING MESSAGES
            Try
                RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Me, ClientData.ReadLine)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            'Reduce CPU Usage
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

So if I were to type in `http://127.0.0.1:8080` into my browser while this server application is running, I would get the following output on my app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Qt8.jpg

After trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` you can see the app has the string `GET / HTTP/1.1` appended to it. The problem though is, my browser will not stop trying to send a request over to this server client so my browser behaves as if the server is unavaliable and the connection just hangs while waiting for a response that'll never come.

I need this server web application to reply back to the browser/client in either an XML, HTML or JSON response to let the browser/client know that "OK, I got your request successfully".

Below is all the code for the GUI of this application:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Server As TCPControl

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Server.IsListening = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Server = New TCPControl
        txtChat.Text = ":: SERVER STARTED ::" & vbCrLf

        AddHandler Server.MessageReceived, AddressOf OnLineReceived
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateTextDelegate(TB As TextBox, txt As String)

    'UPDATE TEXTBOX
    Private Sub UpdateText(TB As TextBox, txt As String)
        If TB.InvokeRequired Then
            TB.Invoke(New UpdateTextDelegate(AddressOf UpdateText), New Object() {TB, txt})
        Else
            If txt IsNot Nothing Then
                TB.AppendText(txt & vbCrLf)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnLineReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)
        UpdateText(txtChat, Data)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'd really appreciate getting some help in getting this Server app to return a response to all clients.